# How to hurdle buggy commits in a develop branch using Git branching/merging?

Tags: git, version-control, merge, workflow, branch

I'm looking into different Git branching strategies and I keep getting stuck at one point.  Let's say you have a master branch.  Additionally, you have a develop branch, which is a branch from master. There are feature/topic branches:

- FixFrontEnd
- FixBackEnd
- ChangeConfig

Three different developers do each change.  The ChangeConfig developer finishes quickly, commits, and merges into the develop branch.  That develop branch is now built and deployed to the Dev environment. Someone tests out this new config and it's approved to move from Dev to the QA environment.  The same success is found for the FixFrontEnd and FixBackEnd branches.  They eventually move along up to QA.

Priorities change the next and the three fixes/features are left sitting in QA.  A new YetAnotherChange fix/feature makes it to QA.  We've found issues with FixFrontEnd and ChangeConfig in QA.  However, YetAnotherChange must go to Production ASAP.

Everything I'm reading says that the develop branch is merged into the master branch, a new build is created for production using master, and it's deployed. Wouldn't FixFrontEnd and ChangeConfig get dragged along in the merge to master?  How is everyone approaching this?

Cherry picking seems to be a complex choice.  I'd like some good idea on how to solve this issue.  I'm looking for a simple solution.  Additionally, let's say that we were able to cherry pick commits.  How can we truly trust that what's cherry picked and built in will work the same way as it did when we built using the develop branch?  Am I getting lost in the woods here somewhere?

Comment: Please show us some diagrams of the various branches.

Comment: In practice, frontend and backend are often treated as separate projects, and may be better as two separate repositories. Maybe that would be worth thinking about in your case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to make changes to production **without changes from FixFrontEnd and ChangeConfig branches**. You can use the way to fix it. Let’s illustrate by below graph:

```
A---B---C master
 \
  D----E----F----G ----L  develop
      /     |     \     \
     H      I      J     K
```

Assume commit histories  from each fix/feature branches as:

**ChangeConfig:** H and then merge to develop branch

**FixFrontEnd:** I and then merge to develop branch

**FixBackEnd:** J and then merge to develop branch

**YetAnotherChange:** K and then merge to develop branch

You just need to find the commit ID for D, F and L, then use `git rebase --onto <commit id for D> <commit id for F> <commit id for L>`, the develop branch will not contain the changes from FixFrontEnd and ChangeConfig branches. And it can go to production. The graph will equal to:

```
A---B---C master
 \
  D ----G ----L  develop
         \     \
          J     K
```

**note:** during rebasing, there may has conflicted file, you need to use `git add <conflicted filename>` and `git rebase --continue`, then the rebase will go on.

Comment: Won't this include FixBackEnd when going to production?  That's not approved for production yet as it is still sitting in QA.  So, why  would we merge that into master?  I thought master was supposed to represent what's in production.

Comment: @LeroyJenkinsCoder, Yes, it won’t include FixFrontEnd and ChangeConfig (issue branches). Sorry for the misunderstanding, I meant it’s ready for production. And all there fix are execute on develop branch, the graph will equal as the last one in my answer (I added it just now).

Answer (score 0):

> Everything I'm reading says that the develop branch is merged into the master branch

Not really: you can:

- rebase `YetAnotherChange` on top of master (and then fast-forward master to `YetAnotherChange` HEAD)
- merge `master` back into `develop`
- rebase the remaining feature branches on top of `develop`.

Any rebasing operation will change the history of those branches, so it needs to be done with a good communication  to the developers working on those branches for them to reset their working tree to the new branch HEAD.